# Returning parameters from FinalBuilder 7 Action Lists

Tags: finalbuilder

If I'm not mistaken, it seems that FinalBuilder 7's action list parameters only support input values. Is there any way I can simulate a workaround for return parameters? I do not want to store return parameters in a global temp variable or even a stack, because I'm calling the same action list multiple times asynchronously.

Here is sample of what I want to do. (Notice the shared use of the same action list)

```
Async Action Group
+-Action Group
| +-Run Action List - [Do Some Calculation]
| +-Replace variable A with return parameter from previous action list
+-Action Group
  +-Run Action List - [Do Some Calculation]
  +-Replace variable B with return parameter from previous action list
```

I'm currently using an INI file in the action list to save return values. The calling method passes a parameter to the action list specifying to which INI key to save to. The calling method then reads the value from the INI from the key.

Surely there has to be a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen any way to return variables from action lists.

That would be an excellent suggestion to post in the FinalBuilder [Wish List forum.](http://www.finalbuilder.com/forum.aspx?aff=7)
Many of requests in the past there are now features of the product.

I think it would require giving scope to variables to something like an Action Group to pull it off.   But it would help some of my scripts as well.  **Update:**  I found that FB 7 [supports Local Variables.](http://www.finalbuilder.com/new-in-finalbuilder-7.aspx)  But it still does not address the needs of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll post my request on their forum. 

At the moment I tell the action list to write the results into an INI file at the key names I pass in as parameters. The calling method then reads the 'return' parameters from the INI once the action list is complete.

I guess another way to return values would be to write key-value text to the log and then have the calling action list put a log output monitor on it, which would then parse and save regex matches to a variable.